# Powershell Get values from nested arrays for Textboxes

Tags: arrays, powershell, user-interface, combobox, textbox

I'm trying to create a gui with comboboxes and textboxes. If the user select a item from the Combobox, the related values from an array should appears in textboxes. Can someone give me a clue? I already tried to enumerat thru the arrays and select the key/value pair with -eq, but unfortunately I was not able to solve it this way.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()


#Arrays
$CB_NDL_Array = @{
                City1 = @{
                    Street = "Test1"
                    Postalcode = "5435"
                }
                City2 = @{
                    Street="Test2"
                    Postalcode="23423"
                }                   
                City3 = @{
                    Street="Test3"
                    Postalcode="234"
                }}   

 $UserManager.controls.AddRange(@($Vorname,$Nachname,$TB_Givenname,$TB_Surname,$Anmeldename,$TB_SamAccountName,$Passwort,$TB_Password,$Niederlassung,$CB_NDL,$Street,$TB_Streetaddress,$City,$TB_City,$PLZ,$TB_Postalcode,$Buero,$TB_Office,$Abteilung,$TB_Department,$Position,$CB_Title,$Firma,$CB_Company,$Manager,$TB_Manager,$Telefon,$TB_OfficePhone,$Mobile,$TB_Mobile,$UserInfo,$Exchange,$RB_exc_yes,$RB_exc_no,$Email_address,$TB_email_address,$CB_Database,$Database,$B_Create))



$CB_NDL                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$CB_NDL.text                     = ""
$CB_NDL.width                    = 100
$CB_NDL.height                   = 20
$CB_NDL.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(110,180)
$CB_NDL.Font                     = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$CB_NDL.SelectedItem


$Street                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Street.text                     = "Strasse"
$Street.AutoSize                 = $true
$Street.width                    = 25
$Street.height                   = 10
$Street.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,210)
$Street.Font                     = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$TB_Streetaddress                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TB_Streetaddress.multiline      = $false
$TB_Streetaddress.width          = 100
$TB_Streetaddress.height         = 20
$TB_Streetaddress.location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(110,210)
$TB_Streetaddress.Font           = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$City                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$City.text                       = "Ort"
$City.AutoSize                   = $true
$City.width                      = 25
$City.height                     = 10
$City.location                   = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,240)
$City.Font                       = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$TB_City                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TB_City.multiline               = $false
$TB_City.width                   = 100
$TB_City.height                  = 20
$TB_City.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(110,240)
$TB_City.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'


$PLZ                             = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$PLZ.text                        = "PLZ"
$PLZ.AutoSize                    = $true
$PLZ.width                       = 25
$PLZ.height                      = 10
$PLZ.location                    = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,270)
$PLZ.Font                        = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$TB_Postalcode                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TB_Postalcode.multiline         = $false
$TB_Postalcode.width             = 100
$TB_Postalcode.height            = 20
$TB_Postalcode.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(110,270)
$TB_Postalcode.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10' 

$CB_NDL.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({
$TB_City.text = $CB_NDL.SelectedItem
$TB_Postalcode.text = $CB_NDL_Array.values | Where-Object{$CB_NDL.SelectedItem} | Where CB_NDL_Array.$_.key -eq "Postalcode"  })

 foreach ($NDL in $CB_NDL_Array.keys){
 $CB_NDL.items.AddRange("$NDL")
 }

foreach ($Title in $CB_Title_Array){
    $CB_Title.items.add("$Title")
    }

foreach ($Company in $CB_Company_Array){
    $CB_Company.items.add("$Company")
    }                                                      
   [void]$UserManager.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Your code as posted will not run. You have errors with missing closing blocks and = signs. Please adjust and repost in an edit

Comment: Sorry, but I just posted the necessary code.

Comment: Is using powershell a requirement? I would just go with a winforms project.

Comment: It is ideal to give us the necessary code to reproduce the problem. While it is sometimes possible to do without it is almost always better to provide a working code set for other users to test with. Especially where forms are concerned. You can drive off people helping as they would need to rebuild the code just so they could start testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$SelectedItem=$CB_NDL.SelectedItem
$TB_Postalcode.text = $CB_NDL_Array.$SelectedItem.Postalcode
```